# UWP app won't launch on second machine

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I started a UWP app on a laptop running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. All was well and good, able to run and test it on both my laptop and my phone with no issues at all.

I added the project to Source Control (private Git server) and pulled the repo on my home PC. The project opens in VS2015 Update 3 on my PC and I can develop and build with no issues. However, I can't seem to run the app on my PC running Windows 10 Build 15063 (same as the laptop). At first I thought it was the temporary certificate, but I tried both creating a new one and adding the one from the working laptop to Source Control. Here is the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in MyUwpApp.exe

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Stack trace:

```
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start(ApplicationInitializationCallback callback)
   at MyUwpApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It doesn't even hit the OnLaunched event on the App.xaml.cs.

I have both machines with Developer Mode enabled as I've used my PC for other projects. It's also worth noting that creating a blank Universal app on the PC works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't want to be stuck with developing on a laptop when I have a more powerful PC (which also runs a LOT cooler than the laptop in this UK heatwave...)

**Edit**

The laptop I created the project on is encrypted with BitLocker. Could this cause the issue?

**Edit 2**

If I create a brand new blank UWP app, it runs fine,  however if I then copy over the source files from the original, install all packages and update namespaces, I get the access denied error again.

Comment: Have you tried running as admin?

Comment: I have indeed. If I start a brand new Universal app on my PC itself, that runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, my Antivirus (Comodo) was containing the applications which meant they didn't have access to anything outside of the AV container.

Unblocking the applications and allowing them to run as normal fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Temporary solution: you can open access to editing and reading for all your bin\debug folders.

The problem is VS does not have the right to write to the bin\debug\appx folder.

**EDIT**

Check your VS user account permissions.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you mean updating the security settings on the folders?

Comment: Hi, Everyone has full access to the bin folder and all subfolders

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The default permissions you show on the left are the same as on my laptop (which works). I'll give Full Control a go on my PC tonight though.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. If I create a blank app it runs okay, if I copy the source code into the new app, it stops working, but it doesn't even hit the app code.

Comment: Are you trying to open the full permission for all VS user accounts? This will have to be done after each build before launch. Put all the checkboxes in the right window. Then click Apply -> apply

Comment: I have indeed. http://imgur.com/Dh4JeFG Here's an image of what my permissions looks like.

Comment: Your permission looks fine. Please, check the package.manifest file. Are you added all the rules for using the application's workflow (microphone, camera, multimedia, etc.)? After that you can delete all the bin / debug application folders (x86, x64, etc.) and recheck this case. Don't forget to give access to the folders for VS user..

Comment: All of the permissions are in, tried deleting the bin folders. This is only a problem on one of two machines.

Comment: After some further research, I think my issue is that the project was created on an encrypted drive, I'm just not sure how to get around the problem.

Comment: Try creating an empty project and moving all the files from the old project to it. If the project works as it should, then replace it with the project in the repository.

Comment: It was my antivirus after all that!